# Positioning images

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

The web page is supposed to look like a phone app, and it has to be responsive. The problem is that I can't position the buttons right. They always move in relation to the 'tablet' whenever I'm re-sizing the browser window. This is what I've tried (with only one button):

CSS

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
}
#tabletBG {
width : 60%;
}
#buttons{
position:absolute;
width:10%;
left:40%;
top:12%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="tablet">
        <img id="tabletBG" src="images/tablet.png" alt="tabletBG"></img>
        <div id="buttons">
            <img id="quienes" src="images/quienes.png" alt="quienes"></img>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I just want the buttons to stick to the tablet. Even if i'm re-sizing the browser window. Is there an easier way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: wHAT CODE HAVE YOU WRITTEN SO FAR KINDLY POST ON FIDDLE ?

Comment: @surajrawat That's all the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding your original question above:**

Try setting the `position` of your `content` div to `absolute`, `fixed`, or `relative`.

This will ensure that your absolutely positioned `buttons` div contained within it will use *it* as a reference point rather than referring its resizing/relocating to the window.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/tixed/1/

**Regarding your comment below:**

> It works, but for an extent. There's a point that if you keep expanding the browser window, the tablet will keep expanding, but the button won't. Here's a [link](http://cupla371preview.hostoi.com/).

The problem there is that your image is only 96 pixels wide, and you've set a CSS rule for all `img` elements to have a `max-width: 100%`. Under these conditions, the image will expand only to the point of its original size (the default action, and not what you want), *and* only to the point of its containing element (by your CSS rule, and to no noticeable effect).

To correct, ideally you would get a larger image. For a quick fix, change its rule to be simply `width: 100%`. This will ensure the image always expands to the point of its containing element.

Comment: That looks like it should work. I'll try it out when I get back to my PC

Comment: Thank you for creating that example for me. It works, but for an extent. There's a point that if you keep expanding the browser window, the tablet will keep expanding, but the button won't. Here's a link to the web page so you can see it yourself:
[Link](http://cupla371preview.hostoi.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I've added to my answer above. Hope it works and explains things (please upvote and checkmark if it does). Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much. 'width: 100%;' works perfectly. I think I'll have to create a bigger button. Sadly I can't upvote yet but I checkmarked your answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, whenever you re-size your browser the images will change their alignment and this is a default behavior of browsers. Only you can make this images to float.

Try this:

```
img{
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, how does this help, exactly?